# Accurate summation of nested products

Tags: c++, floating-point, numerical

I would like to reduce numerical floating-point errors in the following computation.

I have an equation of the following form:

```
b_3+w_3*(b_2+w_2*(b_1+w_1*(b_0+w_0)))
```

where the variable `w` represents some floating-point number in the range `[0,1]` and `b` represents a floating-point constant in the range `[1,~1000000]`. `b` increases monotonically with subscript (though this may not be important). Naturally, this could be extended to any number of terms:

```
b_4+w_4*(c_3+w_3*(b_2+w_2*(b_1+w_1*(b_0+w_0))))
```

This can be defined recursively as:

```
func(x,n):
   if(n==MAX)
      return x
   else
      return func(b[n]+x*w[n],n+1)

func(1,0)
```

If I were doing an online summation, I could use the Kahan Summation Algorithm (Kahan 1965), or one of several other methods ala Higham 1993 or McNamee 2004, to bound the size of my errors. If I were doing online repeated products, I could use some sort of conversion technique to reduce the problem to summation.

As it is, I'm not sure how to approach this particular problem. Does anyone have thoughts (and citations to go with them)?

Thanks!

Higham 1993. "The accuracy of floating point summation". SIAM Journal on Scientific Computing.

Kahan 1965. "Pracniques: further remarks on reducing truncation errors". CACM. "10.1145/363707.363723".

McNamee 2004. "A comparison of methods for accurate summation". SIGSAM Bull. "10.1145/980175.980177".

Comment: The expression you have listed is a polynomial evaluation using Horner's method. It is actually reducing a lot of the error inherent with the computation of "pow" and multiplications in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computation looks similar to a Horner scheme, except that instead of a single variable x, there are different weights w[i] being used at every stage.

There are algorithms for compensated Horner schemes which I think you could adapt for your purposes. See for example theorem 3 and algorithm 2 in the following paper.

P. Langlois, How to Ensure a Faithful Polynomial Evaluation with the Compensated Horner Algorithm. 18th IEEE Symposium on Computer Arithmetic, 25 - 27 June 2007, ARITH '07, pp. 141-149,
http://www.acsel-lab.com/arithmetic/papers/ARITH18/ARITH18_Langlois.pdf

If in algorithm 2 you replace TwoProd (s[i+1], x) with TwoProd (s[i+1], w[i+1]) it seems you would get the desired result, but I have not tried it.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet either, but this was an excellent lead. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

The way you have defined `func`, it evaluates to the following expression:

```
For MAX = n+1, func(1,0) ==

     n     n
   \---  -----
1 + >     | |  w[j]
   /---   | | 
    i=0  j=n-i
```

So, the way I would resolve the sum would be:

```
double s = 0.0;
double a = 1.0;
for (int i = 1; i <= MAX; ++i) {
    a *= w[MAX-i];
    s += a;
}
return 1.0 + s;
```

Even if we treat the `x` input value to `func` as a variable, it only affects the final term. But because of it's range, you should take care in calculating it.

```
double s = 0.0;
double a = 1.0;
double ax = x;
for (int i = 1; i < MAX; ++i) {
    a *= w[MAX-i];
    ax *= w[MAX-i];
    s += a;
}
ax *= w[0];
s += ax;
return 1.0 + s;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I'm afraid I don't see why this would have any special properties which would reduce numeric error. I had thought that compensated summation, `fused multiply-add`, or `fused multiply-accumulate` would be involved, at least. Could you explain?

Comment: @Richard: My processor does not include such an instruction, but I assume the `a *= w[i]; s += a` would be a good candidate for the compiler to apply the instruction when the code is compiled on a platform that has it.